# LUIS.AI Too Many Requests

Tags: azure-language-understanding

In Luis.ai portal, we are getting this error in console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (Too Many Requests)

Publishing and Dispatch will fail as well.

Anyone having the same issue?

We tried two different accounts, both are also having the same issue.

Comment: What action are you taking when this error occurs (e.g., adding intents, editing patterns, training, etc.)? Also, double checking, is this the [LUIS.ai](https://www.luis.ai/home) portal or the (in preview) [preview.luis.ai](https://preview.luis.ai/) portal? Does the issue persist if you try the other?

Comment: The errors still came out today when I click on one of my app:
Screencap: https://ibb.co/HFv0G4h

But today I still can publish though. Yesterday the publishing will fail.

Comment: Can you try accessing via the [preview.luis.aid](https://preview.luis.ai) portal? I'm curious if the issue continues from there.

Comment: Same error appearing in preview too:                                                                                  
https://imgbbb.com/image/LaDpfT

Comment: From the dev tools, can you record your session as these errors occur, save that has a .har file, and then send that to me? I have a LUIS frontend dev who would like to look it over. My email is in my profile.

Comment: I have emailed the HAR to your email. The email subject is "LUIS.AI Too Many Requests". Thanks.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? If so, can you resend the file and double check the email address? I never received the email.

Comment: Your email in the profile is ending with @teksystemsgs.com, is it correct?

Comment: Yes. First name and last name separated by a “.” for the prefix.

Comment: I don't know if you have tried sending the .har file again or not. I haven't received it, though. I would suggest you actually post your issue to LUIS via UserVoice, their preferred medium for communicating with customers. You can do so [here](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-language-understanding-luis).

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have emailed again, but this time with URL to the HAR. Perhaps the previous attachment is too big. I will also submit the their UserVoice.